# How to use the same macro on multiple lines?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro to do the following:

1. When any number is entered into cell I4 run macro.
2. If cell O4 is value 0 then return error message.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'MsgBox Target.Address
    If Not Application.Intersect(Range("I4"), Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
        Call ifzero
    End If
End Sub
    
Sub ifzero()
    If Range("O4") = 0 Then
        Call Mymacro2
    End If
End Sub
    
Sub Mymacro2()
    MsgBox "Zero found"
End Sub
```

How can I do this for I5 & O5, then I6 & O6 all the way to line 262?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see the need for 3 separate subs, but you could do it like this.

```
Dim r As Long

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("I4:I262")) Is Nothing Then
    r = Target.Row
    Call ifzero
End If

End Sub

Sub ifzero()

If Cells(r, "O") = 0 Then
    Call Mymacro2
End If

End Sub

Sub Mymacro2()

MsgBox "Zero found"

End Sub
```

To condense into a single sub

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("I4:I262")) Is Nothing Then
    If Cells(Target.Row, "O") = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Zero found"
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @SJR. I am sure there is a more elegant way to present this but I am new to this. If you have any suggestions to make the code neater it would be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for accepting. Well you could do it all in the worksheet change event, no need to call the other subs.